# Multithreading and connection pool

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have problems with asp.net web service that randomly getting errors like "sql transaction completed no longer usable", "transaction is already commited..."
After read lot of posts I think its problem of shared connection problem bet I was unable to find where the problem is.
Starting from 0 I want to create a "class for 2 porpuoses
- Ensure Connections are closed
- Coding less
The simply class have 2 methods GDT (Give DataTable) and Ejecutar (execute in spanish)

¿Can anybody tell me if this class is well designed for non having problems of sharing connections?

```
Public Class clsAccesoBD2

Public Function GDT(ByVal strSql As String) As DataTable
    Try
        Using Cnn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CadenaPEA").ConnectionString)
            Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, Cnn)
                Using dt As New DataTable
                    da.Fill(dt)
                    Return dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log code here
```

Throw
        End Try
    End Function

```
Public Function Ejecutar(ByVal strSql As String) As Integer
    Try
        Using Cnn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CadenaPEA").ConnectionString)
            Using Cb As New SqlCommand(strSql, Cnn)
                Dim RegistrosAfectados As Integer
                Cnn.Open()
                RegistrosAfectados = Cb.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Cnn.Close()
                Return RegistrosAfectados
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log code here
        Throw
    End Try

End Function
```

End Class

este

Answer (score 0):

close db connection (i.e. `Cnn.Close()`) in `finally` block of `try-catch-finally` construct

Comment: i thought when using "using" statament and an error occurs and the focus moves to catch blcok, the connection automatically closes (because this is out of using block).